# Placing line segments on the x and y-axis

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have an infinite amount of line segments of length 1, and we can place them sequentially on a plane such that each endpoint of the line segment is touching:

1) the x or y-axis.

2) any point on a previously placed line segment.

The objective is to place a line segment that intersects the line y=x at the furthest point away from the origin possible.

What is the furthest point on the line y=x that you can reach by constructing line segments with the given rules? Would it extend to infinity along that line or is there a limit, and if so, what is that limit?

I've thought about this question for a while and I've looked it up online as well but haven't found anything that could help me solve this.

Comment: What is to stop you from letting all the line segments lie along the line $y=x$, starting at the origin and going out as far as you want?

Comment: If the lines were laid out on the line y = x, then a newly placed line segment extending the line out would have to have one of its endpoints on a point not previously occupied by a line segment (Just to clarify, you can't place down all of the line segments in one go), which contradicts the 2nd rule for the endpoints.

Comment: The 1st line segment goes from $(0,0)$ to $(a,a)$, where $a=\sqrt2/2$. The next one goes from $(a,a)$ to $(2a,2a)$; the 3rd one goes from $(2a,2a)$ to $(3a,3a)$, and so on. Each has its endpoint at an endpoint of the previously placed line segment. What's the matter?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Both endpoints of the new segment must be on an axis or previous segment, not just one endpoint. You'd probably start with a segment from $(a,0)$ to $(0,a)$.

Comment: @nickgard is correct, *both* endpoints, at the moment of placing a new line segment, must lie on either the axis or a previously placed line segment.  You cannot start by placing a line segment on (0,0), (a,a) because the point (a,a) does not have a pre-existing line segment crossing the point because you are placing your first line segment.

Comment: OK, got it. Now it's hard to see how you can get very far up the line at all. What have you been able to do, Richard?

Comment: I do know of a potential strategy that involves successive envelopes of sliding ladders, and I will try my best to explain it despite my relatively limited knowledge of mathematical notation (High school contest mathematics).

First, take a line segment and place it so it's endpoints are on (0,0) and (0,1). Then, slide the line segment down such that both endpoints stay on the axies, finishing with endpoints on (1,0) and (0,0).  Then, take the envenlope of the area covered by the line segment, which would be an astroid.  We'll label the curve as  a curve 1. 1/2

Comment: Then, take another line segment and start it above the curve we've just created (curve 1) so that it's endpoints are at (0,1), (0,2), and slide that segment down the axis and curve 1, ending at (2,0), (1,0).  Take the envelope of the area covered by that line segment and call it curve 2.  By following this procedure for curve n as n approaches infinity, it removes the need to find an optimal placement strategy (which would be a whole other problem on it's own) as all points that can be reached are reached.) 2/3

Comment: The astroid is already known, but finding a function for even the 2nd curve has stumped me.  The knowledge required to analyze these curves are likely outside the scope of my skills, so this is all I know so far. And thank you for taking the time to look at my question, I appreciate it. 3/3